# Java System Tray Application in Linux (Ubuntu) launch from service (daemon)

Tags: java, ubuntu, awt

Hi I am writing a java application for linux(ubuntu) which has tray application and daemon application service.

I am able to execute the main application as daemon using yajsw, On User Login to the System I want the service to be notified which is have achieved (I have written script and placed in `/etc/profile.d/` folder the script is getting executed from there I am connecting to the main application using TCP socket connection and pass the logged in user name)

Now from the main application I want to launch the Tray Application in the current logged in user desktop which will show the tray Icon (`SystemTray` of `java.awt`) and popup menu. I have separate `jar` file created for tray application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the script file under /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98script which will be called on user login after session is created so that you can get the $DISPLAY value which is important for the java tray application to start in the session. 
From the script called the daemon java application which is listening on the tcp port
From the daemon java application execute the startapp script pass the logged in username and his DISPLAY in startapp script export DISPLAY and export USERNAME and execute the tray application which will launch in user session and tray is displayed in the same display area

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to launch the tray application in another process

```
Process p = Runtime.
               getRuntime().
               exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","java -jar /path/to/yourjar"});
```

Alternatively, you could just use the OS. Gnome, KDE and Unity all supports automatically starting applications at login. For example, on Gnome, scripts in `~/.config/autostart/` is automatically started when logging in.

Personally, I think the best way to go would be

1. Use the OS to automatically start the system-tray application on login
2. During initialization, check if the daemon is running from the system-tray application
3. Display your updates from the daemon, or show a warning if the deamon is not available

Comment: I used Processbuilder and command as sudo -u <username> java -cp /path/jar mainclass. The tray application starts and SystemTray.isSupported() returns false. If I start the tray application directly from the profile file the problem is if the users kills the application, I will not be able to relaunch the application from the daemon. I am stuck here

Comment: While I still don't think this is the right way to go (starting it from the deamon), are you sure that its started on the right display? Try prepending  "DISPLAY=:n" where n is the number of the x display you want it running on

Comment: I created a script with +x permission to everyone and executed the script using process builder sudo -u <username> /path/script.sh

Comment: But, are you executing it in the correct environment. For example, if you run the daemon before a x server is actually running, and you then create a process. It will not have the DISPLAY environment variable correctly set. So basically, inside your script set DISPLAY=:0 (or whatever display you want to run the java program on) before running the java application

Comment: In the script file as suggested I added the #!/bin/sh export DISPLAY=:0; java -cp /path/jar mainclass. when the first user logs into the system SystemTray.isSupported() returns false, when the second user logged in getting error "cannot Connect to X11 server using ':0' "

Comment: First, can I just confirm that SystemTray.isSupported() returns true when you run the tray application manually? Otherwise this is all a mood point and you have a different problem to solve before worrying about automating it. Secondly, you need to keep track of what display you are using, I just used 0 as an example, you cant just keep reusing that when multiple users are logged in and hope they all happen to share the same display. Give this a read: http://support.objectplanet.com/esupport/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=17

Comment: When I run mannualy I am getting true and it is showing the tray for current user, Is there a way where i can call the daemon after the desktop is launched, but I cannot place the script file in home directory of all the users It should be at system level like /etc/profile.d folder

Comment: I very strongly suspect that this is due to it not running on the right x display / user combination (I noticed you had removed the sudo part of your script in your last comment, was this just to keep the comment short). Regardless, you will certainly need to make sure that you run the command AFTER the x session has completely loaded for the user. I wouldn't use /etc/profile.d for X stuff btw. I'd look at /etc/x11/xinit/xinitrc.d

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41103/discussion-between-user2286306-and-justdanyul)